# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) MERN application

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to get the book details by its id on mern application , but it showing (Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)) Help out to resolve this.
API call is working fine in postman but getting the details in frontend.

frontend code

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import bookThree from '../assets/Images/book-3.jpg'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import { getExchangeAPI } from '../Services/allAPI'

function ExchangeView() {
    const {id} = useParams()
    const [exchangeData,setExchangeData] = useState("")

    useEffect(() =>{
        const exchangeDetails = async () =>{
            try{
                const result = await getExchangeAPI(id)
                setExchangeData(result.data)
            }catch(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
        exchangeDetails()
    },[id])
  return (
    <>
    <div className="container">
        <div className="row mt-5">
            <div className="col-lg-5">
                <img src={bookThree} alt="" />
            </div>
            <div className="col-lg-6">
                <h1>{exchangeData?.title}</h1>
                <h3>{exchangeData?.author}</h3>
                <p><span className='fw-bolder'>About the Book:</span> {exchangeData?.about}</p>
                <div className='mt-4'>
                    <h3>Exchange for : {exchangeData?.exchangeTitle} by         {exchangeData?.exchangeAuthor}</h3>
                    <button className="btn btn-info rounded">Exchange</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

controller.js

```
export const getExchangeAPI = async (id,reqHeader) =>{
    return await commonAPI("GET",`${SERVER_URL}/books/exchange/${id}`,"",reqHeader)
}
```

apicall

```
export const getExchangeAPI = async (id,reqHeader) =>{
    return await commonAPI("GET",`${SERVER_URL}/books/exchange/${id}`,"",reqHeader)
}
```

I am expecting to view the details of the book with the id.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would check is to make sure when you call api in your useEffect it is calling the right endpoint, to check this go to network tab in your developer tools and see what url its calling. If it looks correct I would check that ID is getting set up correctly with custom hooks useParams. Lastly you could console log to see if the endpoint was hit if it is being hit, it could be the id you are passing to api call does not exist in DB resulting in a 404.